# ASP.NET MVC how to avoid call URLs directy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an action method in my controler which perform a delete action:

```
private ActionResult Delete(int id)
{           
     if (delete(id))
     {
          return Content("success");
     } 
     else 
     {
          return Content("something went wrong!");
     }

}
```

I call it from my view with jQuery ajax in this way:

```
jQuery('#NotificationArea').load('/MyController/Delete/5');
```

To do this I need register the controller-action in global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Delete",
   "MyController/Delete/{id}",
   new { controller = "MyController", action = "Delete" }
);
```

But I have realized that it is dangerous since everyone could call this action directly from the browser and change the id to delete a different element:

```
myDomain.com/MyController/Delete/20
```

How can I avoid this potential security problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [HttpPost] attribute on top of the delete function. This way, it will work only if your loaded page posts that data and hitting that url directly won't work.

There is also something that you can put on the page so that only posts from the same page will be valid. Some attribute. Let me get back to you on that.

Comment: Should be decorated by the AcceptVerbs attribute.

Comment: I was talking about something else. People can still create a form and then post it to his delete function. There is a way to prevent that, but looks like this is all that Jero was looking for.

Comment: Additional info is welcome, if there is a way to secure it in a more efficient way please share it.

Comment: Ok here you go.. to prevent cross site forgery: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

Comment: Indeed that is really a secure way to avoid calling the delete methods. 

It doesn't fit 100% with my original question because I am not using POST methods but GET, anyway as I read later:

"It only works with POST requests, not GET requests. Arguably this isn’t a limitation, because under the normal HTTP conventions, you shouldn’t be using GET requests for anything other than read-only operations."

So the real answer to my question is: change from GET to POSt and use  the AntiForgeryToken technic.

Answer (score 1):

You could essentially decorate your Delete action method with an AcceptVerbs attribute. You may read this [article](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/01/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because.aspx) for great detail.

Comment: No worries. Glad the article helped :)

Comment: Sorry man but Vishal Kumaris is right, an attacker could just build a JavaScript call with the necessary "Delete" parameter and be successful. But thanks anyway, it is useful too to know about the AcceptVerbs attribute.